# Generating Karaf Bundle

Tags: maven, karaf, sdn, opendaylight

I've got a hello world opendaylight app (created following the tutorials) which compiles using a mvn clean install, and appears when I run the karaf package that is also generated.

However I am unable to get it to run in another ODL install (downloaded the binary with all the other packages from the website), and even using a

```
bundle:install mvn:org.andrew.test
```

results in unable to install bundle (tried copying to deploy and system/org/andrew....)

How do you get a bundle which can be used in another install?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to `bundle:install` instead of `feature:install` ?

What most existing ODL projects do for you, and what the [example generated by the archetype](https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/OpenDaylight_Controller:MD-SAL:Startup_Project_Archetype) should also show you how to do for your custom org.andrew.test one (have you used the archetype? try it..) is that there is a local karaf/ artifact which correctly depends on the features/odl-something feature of your example, and lets you install it, which will install your bundle/s.

In theory and if you really know what you are doing, you can also get it to work for what you call "in another install" in your question, but [you have to use `repo-app` and what not](https://github.com/vorburger/openstack-devstack-opendaylight-vagrant/tree/master/Daexim) - most people do not use it like that AFAIK (at least in ODL development); so I wouldn't bother, if I were you.

If you want to learn more about this in general outside of OpenDaylight, the [general Karaf documentation manual](http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/) is not bad.  Beware that in ODL we've tweaked a few things though; for example, we have (intentionally) disabled the direct installation from ~/.m2/repository (for better isolation).